# Debouncing In Angular Dispatching Action

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngxs

How do I debounce in Angular when I try to call a network request through dispatching it?
I don't want to call network request every keystroke.
I applied this below but its not working.

**TS**

```js
      search(searchValue: any) {
        this.loadingPlatNo = true;
        const searchTerm = searchValue.searchTerm;
    
        this.store
          .dispatch(new GetCarInformation(searchTerm || ''))
          .pipe(debounce(2000), takeUntil(this.destroy$))
          .subscribe((val) => {
            this.loadingPlatNo = false;
            this.car_informations = val.carInformation.car_informations;
          });
      }
```

**HTML**

```html
    <ng-select
      #select
      (search)="search(select)"
      [items]="car_informations"
      bindLabel="plate_no"
      bindValue="plate_no"
      bindLabel="plate_no"
      clearAllText="Clear"
      [closeOnSelect]="true"
      [searchable]="true"
      [clearable]="true"
      [hideSelected]="false"
      [multiple]="false"
      [loading]="loadingPlateNo"
      loadingText="Loading..."
      addTagText="CREATE NEW PLATE NO: "
      [addTag]="addNewPlateNo"
      placeholder="Select plate no."
      formControlName="plate_no"
    ></ng-select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operator you want is actually `debounceTime(2000)` as `debounce(...)` takes a callback function.

However, in this case they would both only debounce the response, not the request. That's because debounce delays notifications **emitted by the source Observable**. It does not delay subscribing to the source observable. The way you were trying to use it, debounce would actually just delay executing your callback function by two seconds after the response was received.

To debounce making an http request you need a second observable to apply the debounce before making the request. A `Subject` works well for this. You `pipe` the subject with a debounce and the api call, then call `next()` on every keystroke. The pipe will only make the api call if `next()` has not been called for the allotted debounce time.

Here's a simple example to show you the pattern:

```js
const apiCall$ = of('pong').pipe(delay(4000)); // Simulates 4 second api call
```

```js
  pingSubject$ = new Subject<void>();
  debouncedPing$ = this.pingSubject$.pipe(
    debounceTime(2000),
    switchMap(() => {
      console.log('ping');
      return apiCall$;
    })
  );

  ngOnInit() {
    this.debouncedPing$.subscribe((res) => console.log(res));
  }

  ping() {
    this.pingSubject$.next();
  }
```

```html
<button (click)="ping()">PING</button>
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2mjjf2?file=src/app/app.component.html

This won't make the request until 2 seconds after you stop clicking the button (you will see `ping` in the console). Then the request will take 4 seconds to complete.

Since I used `switchMap`, if a new request is started before the previous has responded, the previous request will be cancelled. You can use `mergeMap` if you do not want to cancel ongoing requests.

---

Your situation is a bit more complicated since you have a parameter.

I would probably implement it like this:

```js
  searchSubject$ = new Subject<any>();
  debouncedSearch$ = this.searchSubject$.pipe(
    debounceTime(2000),
    takeUntil(this.destroy$),
    switchMap((searchValue) => this.store.dispatch(new GetCarInformation(searchValue || '')))
  );

  ngOnInit() {
    this.debouncedSearch$.subscribe((val: any) => {
      this.loadingPlatNo = false;
      this.car_informations = val.carInformation.car_informations;
    });
  }

  search(searchValue: any) {
    this.loadingPlatNo = true;
    this.searchSubject$.next(searchValue);
  }
```

Comment: @Joseph I made a slight update, I forgot you can just pass the parameter through the subject.